# Add github integration to Xcode 6 project created without git

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode6

I have a project I created in Xcode 6.

When I created it I'm pretty sure I unchecked git. "Keep things simple!" I thought.

Now I wish to opensource my project. 
I've created a new repo on github.

Do I have to create a fresh Xcode project the DOES have git, and copy the contents across?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to create a new Xcode project that has 'Use source control' selected.

All you need to do is go to GitHub, create a new repository (shown below), and upload your Xcode project. [image: create a new repository]